# Assembly.CreateInstance type conversion returns null

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I'm trying to load and use a DLL at runtime and this works fine:

```
var pluggin = asm2.CreateInstance("ParserTest.Interface", true) as iPluggin;
```

But this doesn't (I need to loop through the DLL files in a specific folder to find the right ones implementing iPluggin interface):

```
...
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll.FullName);
if (asm.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(q => q.GetInterface(tName) != null) == null) continue;
Project.ProcessList.Add(asm.CreateInstance(tName, true) as iPluggin);
...
```

Doing some research in debug mode I found out that:

```
asm.CreateInstance(tName, true)
```

returns the correct object, but when trying to cast it to iPluggin the result is null.
Any idea why?

Comment: Because it returns an object of an incompatible type (?).

Comment: CreateInstance returns a System.Object as expected, the only difference i see between the code that Works and the one that doesn't is that i provide the interface name manually ("ParserTest.Interface") in the first case

Comment: `as` returns null instead of raising an exception when a conversion fails, due to what Ondrej said.

Comment: Yes, but if it doesn't implement that interface, "as" returns null. So: where is that interface declared?

Comment: The interface is declared on a separate DLL, that both the pluggin being loaded and the running code use. the DLL being loaded in both cases is the same "ParserTest.dll", so yes it implements the iPluggin interface, that i'm sure of.

Comment: @FranCasadome Then it looks like you're somehow loading the assembly that declares `iPluggin` twice. Have you tried recompiling everything? Aren't you loading that assembly from a strange place, or something like that?

Comment: @svick You are right, that was exactly the issue: the DLL where the interface is defined was among the others and was being loaded twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistery solved althought I don't understand it.

The DLL that defines de interface (SDK.dll) was among the ones being checked.
I removed it manually in my query and all woks as expected now.
This is my final code:

```
    var plugins =
        from fi in di.GetFiles("*.dll").Where(p => p.Name.ToUpper() != "SDK.DLL")
        let asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(fi.FullName)
        from t in asm.GetExportedTypes()
        where t.GetInterface(typeof(iPluggin).Name) != null
        select asm.CreateInstance(t.FullName, true) as iPluggin;
    Project.ProcessList.AddRange(plugins);
```

Comment: You could use `Type.IsAssignableFrom` method instead of checking specifically for interface type which would cover both base-classes and interfaces. And since you have the type reference itself, use `Activator.CreateInstance(t)` rather than have it do another lookup in the assembly by type name (especially since you do a non-case-sensitive search. Theoretically there could be a type of the same name but with different case sensitivity!)

Comment: You may also want to check that the type has a parameterless constructor or catch (and report) the `MissingMethodException` which fires if the `iPlugin` implementation provided did not implement a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar:

```
private readonly Type _pluginbaseType = typeof(BasePlugin);

public AssemblyPlugin(Assembly assembly)
{

    Type[] _plugins = _assembly.GetExportedTypes()
        .Where(t => t.BaseType.IsSubclassOf(_pluginbaseType)
        .ToArray();
}
```

After this you can:

```
BasePlugin plugin = (BasePlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType);
```

You should prefer a base class instead of an interface.

Comment: Why exactly is a base class better than an interface?

Comment: Ok i found out something: if all the DLLs being checked for the interface implement it then it Works fine. As soon as one of them doesn't the rest of them return null whether they implement it or not. :/

Comment: @svick: A base class can have base functionality and an interface not. In this case, you maybe prefer to provid a specific behavior of all plugins. The main reasoning behind the preference for abstract base classes is versioning, because you can always add a new virtual member to an abstract base class without breaking existing clients. That's not possible with interfaces.

And here: [Choosing Between Classes and Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229013.aspx).